# Differentiating various Qx fixed-point types?

Tags: c, signal-processing, fixed-point

How do you differentiate between various Qx fixed-point types in your code?

Would something like this be acceptable:

```
typedef int32_t q31;
typedef int32_t q25;
typedef int32_t q23;
typedef int32_t q15;
```

and then (usage example):

```
q23 x;
q23 y;
q31 out;
.
.
.    
out = do_something_input_q23s_output_q31(x,y);
// etc.
```

Do the above typedefs make sense? What would be the most appropriate solution?

Comment: Not really - you can't specify more than 6 decimal places in a 32-bit float.  Are you creating a fixed point library?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand.

Comment: How much type safety do you want? If a lot, you could wrap types to structs, at the expense of more clumsy usage. Simple typedef over `int32_t` doesn't buy you any compile time checks. In that case you might benefit more from Hungarian notation as [described here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

Comment: Thanks. If I understood correctly, you'd do something like: `int q23SomeVariable;``int q23OtherVariable;`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, you'd use prefix to make easier to see possible mistakes. And don't forget conversion functions `int q25New = q25Fromq23(q23Old);`. But I'd consider using a little more descriptive names than `q23`.

Comment: Note if you do use Hungarian notation, those `typedef`s are not necessarily bad, even if you don't get much compiler help. It's not possible give one true solution, without knowing the complete picture of your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each fixed point integer in a struct, which will make the compiler enforce the type. I don't know how that effects performance.

I suppose you could use preprocessor magic to switch the implementation to naked ints for release.